# Jupyter Notebook in VScode Not Exporting Pyplot Titles

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a simple, side by side pie chart in a jupyter notebook in vscode with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,10))

ax[0].pie(priv_pub,
        labels = ['Private', 'Public'],
        textprops = {'color': 'white'},
        autopct= '%.1f',
        explode= (0,0.1)
        )
ax[0].set_title('Amount of Private vs. Public Universities',
             color = 'white'
        )
ax[1].pie(priv_pub_100,
        labels = ['Private', 'Public'],
        textprops = {'color': 'white'},
        autopct= '%.1f',
        explode= (0,0.1)
        )
ax[1].set_title('Amount of Private vs. Public Universities: Top 100',
            color = 'white'
          )
plt.show()
```

The charts come our great in the notebook, with the titles and labels printed too. However, when I export to PDF or HTML, the labels and titles both disappear

Any advice? (I've also tried just making a single pie chart, and the same is happening).

Comment: What colour are you setting the `figure.facecolor` of the figure? If it's white as well then they won't show up.

Comment: Correct-- this was exactly the issue. My notebook's default background is dark grey, whereas the html printout is white. So it was showing in my notebook, but not in the html. Thanks!